# How can we exit an thread explicitly which start by bat file?

Tags: multithreading, bash, batch-file, cmd, windows-7

I have the below **.bat** files

a.bat:

```
start /b b.bat
echo b.bat exited
```

b.bat:

```
rem how can we quit below cmd explicit? 
%ADB% shell cat /path/to/cat > log
```

`shell cat /path/to/cat` doesn't quit explicitly, unless <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ <kbd>C</kbd> is used to quit explicitly.

**Q**

- What should we do if `b.bat exited` printed for wait 5s?
- How can I do that only wait 5s for cmd `shell cat /path/to/cat >log`?

Comment: @Cyrus Windows 7 32bit

Comment: Try `call` instead of `start /b`

Comment: @Compo no-matter `call xx.bat` or `start /b xx.bat` . will wait for xx.bat return. My Question is: do not wait for return for default,just wait for 5s(don't care xx.bat were run complete or not)

Comment: Your question makes no sense then. Line 2 of a.bat prints regardless of what happens in b.bat. All you therefore need to do is add a new line 2 in a.bat ` timeout 5 /nobreak>nul. _(the contents of b.bat have no bearing on this question then!)_.

Comment: @compo ,Yeah,`timeout` cmd was blocked the bat cmd in current line. `start aa.exe` will cost 10 mins. But the wait time for `start aa.exe` is only 5s. `timeout 5 /nobreak>null start aa.exe` means that wait for 5s and then start aa.exe.  I want to know:first start aa.exe and then only wait for 5s

Comment: You are still making no sense; putting the second line as timeout like I stated starts b.bat waits for five seconds then echoes the exited message. If that's not what you want or what is happening, edit your question accordingly.

Comment: IMO, you're pushing the limits of what it is sensible to do in batch, but I believe the usual trick is to use the `start` command to launch the child in a separate window with a unique title, and then use `taskkill` to kill all processes associated with that title.